# How to get index Slot Particle or Delete Slot Particle by Name?

Tags: particles

[image]

After applying Particle Modifier, the Particle slot still exists. As shown above, I want to delete slot "SF_Plane_P_Sphere.002", but slot "SF_Plane_P_Sphere.001" is actived.
And as far as I know to remove it, i need to know its index to be active & remove

```
bpy.context.object.particle_systems.active_index = 2

bpy.ops.object.particle_system_remove()
```

but I don't know how to get the index by its name. Or is there a way to delete it by its name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the particle system slot index using:

```
index = bpy.context.object.particle_systems.find("the name you want")
```

Comment: it''s work, Thanks ^^