# how to change particle system display in viewport by particle's name?

Tags: python, modifiers, particles

[image]

The particle system is associated with the modifier. Switching on and off the display of the particle system is equal to switching on and off the display of the modifier. So how to switch on and off the display of the particle system by code if particle system’s name ≠ modifier’s name?

Comment: and how to remove particle system by name(not active index)?（sovled）https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193274/how-to-get-index-slot-particle-or-delete-slot-particle-by-name

Answer (score 2):

If your particle system was on the default cube and had the default name the way to disable display would be

```py
import
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers['ParticleSystem'].show_viewport = False
```

`show_viewport` is a Boolean toggle, so turning it back on is simply setting it to `True`.

If an object has multiple particle systems, each will have its own modifier, and each modifier will have a unique name.  So the generic form of the reference is

`object.modifiers[UNIQUE_NAME].show_viewport`

where `object` is any object that can have a particle system modifier.  In addition to selection from `bpy.data.objects` you can, for example use the active object: `bpy.context.active_object.modifiers['ParticleSystem'].show_viewport`.

If you want to turn off the modifier you have to find the modifier.  If you know the particle system name but it's different than the modifier then you can find the modifier with this code:

```py
ps = [modifier for modifier in bpy.data.objects['Plane'].modifiers if modifier.type == 'PARTICLE_SYSTEM']
pa = [p for p in ps if p.particle_system.name == 'alice']
modifier = pa[0]
```

substituting the name of the object for `'Plane'` and the name of the particle system for `'alice'`

Comment: I know that the display can be changed through the modifier, but when the particle is renamed, the name of the modifier is inconsistent with the name of the particle, how can I change the display through the particle's name? or  how to get name of modifier through  the particle's name. and how to get index of particle through  the particle's name.